# Error "No credentials were available in client certificate" using Excel VBA to call Rest API

Tags: excel, vba, rest

I'm trying to do some integrations using rest APIs.

I get an error:

> No credentials were available in client certificate.

Code I tried:

Example 1

```vb
Dim url As String
Dim body As String
    
'URL for retrieving bearer token
url = Cells(1, 2) & "/oauth2/v0/token"
body = "client_id=" & Cells(2, 2) & " client_secret=" & Cells(3, 2) & " grant_type=refresh_token" & " refresh_token" & Cells(4, 2)

Dim objHTTP As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Set objHTTP = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

objHTTP.SetAutoLogonPolicy AutoLogonPolicy_Always

objHTTP.SetClientCertificate "DigiCert"

'    objHTTP.Option(WinHttp.WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = WinHttp.WinHttpRequestSslErrorFlags.SslErrorFlag_Ignore_All
 objHTTP.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = 256

Call objHTTP.Open("POST", url, False)

objHTTP.Send

objHTTP.WaitForResponse

Debug.Print objHTTP.ResponseText
```

Example 2

```vb
EndPoint = "https://us2.api.concursolutions.com/oauth2/v0/token"
Payload = "client_id=" & Cells(2, 2) & "&client_secret=" & Cells(3, 2) & "&grant_type=refresh_token" & "&refresh_token=" & Cells(4, 2)

Dim xmlhttp
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

xmlhttp.setOption(2) = 13056
'strCert = "Friendly Name"
xmlhttp.setOption(3) = "DigiCert"
'xmlhttp.SetClientCertificate "DigiCert"
xmlhttp.Open "POST", EndPoint, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "HTTP/1.1"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "us.api.concursolutions.com"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "437"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "concur-correlationid", "ExcelVBA-Gpaparelli"
xmlhttp.Send Payload

Debug.Print xmlhttp.ResponseText
```

How do I get some response from this specific endpoint (even if it is a failed response)?

https://us2.api.concursolutions.com/oauth2/v0/token

I tried:
Different classes: MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0, WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Setting option (2) to ignore SSL errors
Setting option (3) to assign certificate (I tried exporting the website certificate and importing to MMC)
Messing around with the request header parameters
Changing computers (one with Win11 and no anti-virus)

The same requests are working on Postman.

Comment: Maybe try the suggestion here?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778478/478884

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by changing the object from ServerXMLHTTP to XMLHTTP.
Here is the example should someone needs it

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")       
xmlhttp.Open "POST", EndPoint, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "HTTP/1.1"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "us.api.concursolutions.com"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "437"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "concur-correlationid", "ExcelVBA-Gpaparelli"
xmlhttp.Send Payload
```